# Not all locales are generated in sitemap.xml of a docusaurus website

Tags: internationalization, sitemap, docusaurus, xml-sitemap, sitemap.xml

I have a website made by docusaurus `2.0.0-beta.18`. Initially it was in English, then I added Chinese version for many pages with `i18`. So a page like `https://www.mywebsite.com/zh-CN/docs/a-page` displays well contents in Chinese.

However, I just realized that none of the chinese pages are in `sitemap.xml`. As a conseuqence, none of the chinese pages are indexed in Google.

Does anyone know how to fix that?

PS: (part of) docusaurus.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
  title: 'my website',
  tagline: 'The tagline of my site',
  onBrokenLinks: 'ignore',
  url: 'https://www.mywebsite.com',
  baseUrl: '/', // if we use GitHub Pages, we need to set this to '/docusaurus/', and also change routing links in some pages
  favicon: 'img/favicon.ico',
  organizationName: 'softtimur', // Usually your GitHub org/user name.
  projectName: 'docusaurus', // Usually your repo name.
  trailingSlash: false,
  plugins: [
    path.resolve(__dirname, './plugins/monaco-loader'),
  ],
  themeConfig: {
    navbar: {
      title: 'my website',
      logo: {
        alt: 'My Site Logo',
        src: 'img/logo.svg',
      },
      items: [
        {
          label: 'Documentation', position: 'left',
          items: [
            { label: 'Introduction', to: 'docs/introduction' },
            { label: 'Getting Started', to: 'docs/try-samples' }
          ]
        },
        { to: 'demo', label: 'Live Demo', position: 'left' }, // to src/pages/demo.js
        {
          label: 'Persons', position: 'left',
          items: [
            { label: 'Get my website', to: 'docs/consumer-buy' },
            { label: 'Follow Free Videos and Contents', to: 'docs/free-videos' },
            { label: 'Request a Help', to: 'docs/help-your-work' }
          ]
        },
        {
          label: 'Businesses', position: 'left',
          items: [
            { label: 'Get my website Together', to: 'docs/group-buy' },
            { label: 'Other Services', to: 'docs/web-development' }
          ]
        },
        {
          label: 'Language and Programming', position: 'left',
          items: [
            { label: 'Course in English', to: 'https://go.mywebsite.com/RJ2HPz' },
            { label: 'Course in Chinese', to: 'https://go.mywebsite.com/2KjQzL' },
          ]
        }
        ,
        {
          to: '#',
          position: 'right',
        },
        {
          to: '/logout',
          label: 'Sign Out',
          position: 'right',
        },
        {
          to: '/login',
          label: 'Sign In',
          position: 'right',
        },
        {
          type: 'localeDropdown',
          position: 'right',
        },

      ],
    },
    footer: {
      style: 'dark',
      links: [
        {
          title: 'Documentation',
          items: [
            {
              label: 'Try samples',
              to: 'docs/try-samples',
            },
            {
              label: 'Installation',
              to: 'docs/installation',
            }
          ],
        },
        {
          title: 'Philosophy and Research',
          items: [
            {
              label: 'Fundamentals',
              to: 'docs/fundamentals'
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          title: 'Community',
          items: [
            {
              label: 'LinkedIn',
              href: 'https://www.linkedin.com/in/softtimur/'
            }
          ],
        },
        {
          title: 'Company',
          items: [
            {
              label: 'About Us',
              to: 'docs/about-us'
            },
            {
              label: '❤ We are hiring!',
              to: 'docs/hiring'
            }
          ],
        }
      ],
    },
  },
  presets: [
    [
      '@docusaurus/preset-classic',
      {
        googleAnalytics: {
          trackingID: 'UA-68622074-6',
        },
        docs: {
          sidebarPath: require.resolve('./sidebars.js'),
        },
        theme: {
          customCss: require.resolve('./src/css/custom.css'),
        },
        sitemap: {
          changefreq: 'weekly',
          priority: 0.5,
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
  scripts : [
    '/js/patch.js'
  ],
  i18n: {
    defaultLocale: 'en',
    locales: ['en', 'zh-CN'],  // Add 'zh-CN' here
    localeConfigs: {
      en: {
        label: 'English',
        htmlLang: 'en-GB',
      },
      'zh-CN': {   // Add this section for Simplified Chinese
        label: '简体中文',
        htmlLang: 'zh-Hans',
      },
    },
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docusaurus generates a separate sitemap.xml for each local

https://github.com/facebook/docusaurus/discussions/9548#discussioncomment-7579815